# No match for call operator when std::bind-ing a std::function with a std::future

Tags: c++, c++17, future, std-function

When I try to `std::bind` a `std::future<T>` to a `std::function<void(std::future<T>)>` I get a compiler i.e. template error I not completely understand. It seems to me the `std::bind` template deduction goes haywire but I am also not sure how to properly stick the template parameters manually.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>

int main() {
    using my_result_t = int;
    std::function<void(std::future<my_result_t>)> callback {
        [] (auto result) {
            try {
                auto result_value = result.get();
                std::cout << "Result " << result_value << "\n";
            } catch (std::exception& exception) {
                std::cerr << exception.what() << "\n";
                throw;
            }
        }
    };
    std::promise<my_result_t> promise{};
    promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error("Foo")));
    std::future<my_result_t> future = promise.get_future();
    auto f = std::bind(callback, std::move(future));
    f();
}
```

> ```
> 24:7: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::function<void(std::future<int>)>(std::future<int>)>) ()’
>   24 |     f();
> ```

Full error text from gcc :

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled5.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/markus/CLionProjects/untitled5/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/markus/CLionProjects/untitled5/main.cpp:24:7: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::function<void(std::future<int>)>(std::future<int>)>) ()’
   24 |     f();
      |       ^
In file included from /home/markus/CLionProjects/untitled5/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:480:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
  480 |  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:480:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional: In substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _Fn, class _CallArgs, class ... _BArgs> using _Res_type_impl = typename std::result_of<_Fn&(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Mu_type<_BArgs, _CallArgs>&& ...)>::type [with _Fn = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; _BArgs = {std::future<int>}; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:447:8:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _CallArgs> using _Res_type = std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Res_type_impl<_Functor, _CallArgs, _Bound_args ...> [with _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:478:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:443:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::function<void(std::future<int>)>&(std::future<int>&)>’
  443 |  using _Res_type_impl
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:491:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
  491 |  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:491:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional: In substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _Fn, class _CallArgs, class ... _BArgs> using _Res_type_impl = typename std::result_of<_Fn&(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Mu_type<_BArgs, _CallArgs>&& ...)>::type [with _Fn = std::add_const<std::function<void(std::future<int>)> >::type; _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; _BArgs = {std::add_const<std::future<int> >::type}; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:454:8:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _CallArgs, template<class _CallArgs, template<class> class __cv_quals> template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class> class __cv_quals> using _Res_type_cv = std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Res_type_impl<typename __cv_quals<typename std::enable_if<(bool)((std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value + 1)), _Functor>::type>::type, _CallArgs, typename __cv_quals<_Bound_args>::type ...> [with _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; __cv_quals = std::add_const; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:489:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:443:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<const std::function<void(std::future<int>)>&(const std::future<int>&)>’
  443 |  using _Res_type_impl
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:509:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
  509 |  operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:509:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional: In substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _Fn, class _CallArgs, class ... _BArgs> using _Res_type_impl = typename std::result_of<_Fn&(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Mu_type<_BArgs, _CallArgs>&& ...)>::type [with _Fn = std::add_volatile<std::function<void(std::future<int>)> >::type; _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; _BArgs = {std::add_volatile<std::future<int> >::type}; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:454:8:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _CallArgs, template<class _CallArgs, template<class> class __cv_quals> template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class> class __cv_quals> using _Res_type_cv = std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Res_type_impl<typename __cv_quals<typename std::enable_if<(bool)((std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value + 1)), _Functor>::type>::type, _CallArgs, typename __cv_quals<_Bound_args>::type ...> [with _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; __cv_quals = std::add_volatile; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:506:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:443:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<volatile std::function<void(std::future<int>)>&(volatile std::future<int>&)>’
  443 |  using _Res_type_impl
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:521:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
  521 |  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:521:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional: In substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _Fn, class _CallArgs, class ... _BArgs> using _Res_type_impl = typename std::result_of<_Fn&(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Mu_type<_BArgs, _CallArgs>&& ...)>::type [with _Fn = std::add_cv<std::function<void(std::future<int>)> >::type; _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; _BArgs = {std::add_cv<std::future<int> >::type}; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:454:8:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class _CallArgs, template<class _CallArgs, template<class> class __cv_quals> template<class _Functor, class ... _Bound_args> template<class> class __cv_quals> using _Res_type_cv = std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Res_type_impl<typename __cv_quals<typename std::enable_if<(bool)((std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value + 1)), _Functor>::type>::type, _CallArgs, typename __cv_quals<_Bound_args>::type ...> [with _CallArgs = std::tuple<>; __cv_quals = std::add_cv; _Functor = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>; _Bound_args = {std::future<int>}]’
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:518:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:443:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<const volatile std::function<void(std::future<int>)>&(const volatile std::future<int>&)>’
  443 |  using _Res_type_impl
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind` stores copies of its arguments (here a move-constructed `future`), and later, uses them as lvalue arguments (with some exceptions to that rule that include reference wrappers, placeholders and other bind expressions; none applicable here).

`std::future` is not copy-constructible. That is, a function that accepts a parameter *by-value*, of a type that is not copy-constructible, like your `callback` does, is not callable with an lvalue.

In order to make your code work, you need to adjust the signature of the callback:

```
std::function<void(std::future<my_result_t>&)> callback = [] (auto& result) {
//                                        ~^~                    ~^~
```

Preferably, though, don't use `std::bind` at all.

Comment: Weird, I tough It would be move constructed by giving bind an rvalue by the move wrapper.

Comment: @Superlokkus It can't. `f()` can appear multiple times. Only the first would work. That, however, is how `std::thread` works, which does indeed uses rvalues when calling a callback.

Comment: Hmm I am not completely following why I can't bind to the rvalue, but it still helps a lot, thx!

Comment: And by "Preferably, though, don't use std::bind at all." I assume you are suggesting calling the std::function in a lambda as f?

Comment: @Superlokkus You *are* move-constructing a copy of the argument from an rvalue, inside a callable object returned from `std::bind`, but applying `operator()` it has to use lvalues of that copies, so they can be used several times (that callable can be invoked several times). And yes, I mean to use lambdas directly, without even wrapping them in `std::function` if there's no specific need to.

Comment: Ah I see so its the different intended semantics between std::bind which by template deduction wants to create/return a callable which would call the lvalue parameter with an lvalue stored within the callable object, while a mutable move capturing lambda as alternative would use an rvalue to the its stored/captured future?!

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth mentioning that the actual solution is used was to replace the bind by a lambda. What I forgot to mention in my question was that changing the signature of the callback to a reference is not a suitable option for me, since the f callable will be copied/moved into an asynchronous queue, i.e. reactor pattern, i.e. `boost::asio::post`. A reference would rise lifetime challenges for the lifetime of that future. I didn't mentioned it first since I hope it would still be somehow possible with `std::bind`, but @piotr-skotnicki did nicely explain why its not possible. So for completeness of other searches without further ado:

```
std::future<my_result_t> future = promise.get_future();
auto f = [callback, future = std::move(future)] () mutable{
    callback(std::move(future));
};
f();
```